# ERROR in : Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies. This might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files

Tags: angular, npm, build, electron

I'm working on angular plus electron app. I'm unable to give build for windows and linux apps.

This is the error that I am getting. When I run this command : npm run electron:windows

```
PS D:\trackly\TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master> npm run electron:windows

> Trackly@5.2.5 electron:windows D:\trackly\TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master
> npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --windows


> Trackly@5.2.5 build:prod D:\trackly\TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master
> npm run build -- -c production


> Trackly@5.2.5 build D:\trackly\TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master
> npm run postinstall:electron && npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build "-c" "production"


> Trackly@5.2.5 postinstall:electron D:\trackly\TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master
> node postinstall


> Trackly@5.2.5 electron:serve-tsc D:\trackly\TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master
> tsc -p tsconfig-serve.json

 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 activelooking for undefined provider for the NgModule 'NgxMaterialTimepickerModule in D:/trackly/TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master/node_modules/ngx-material-timepicker/ngx-material-timepicker.d.ts'Date: 2019-01-04T07:50:40.006Z Hash: da67c7a8c12b72458ed5 Time: 13833ms chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {1} main.9868d9b237c3a48c54da.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered] chunk {2} polyfills.85f47f0bf59079cbc23a.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered] chunk {3} styles.b355ced00b1297914fd7.css (styles) 235 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in : Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies. This might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Trackly@5.2.5 build: `npm run postinstall:electron && npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build "-c" "production"` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the Trackly@5.2.5 build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\ankus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-04T07_50_40_079Z-debug.log npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Trackly@5.2.5 build:prod: `npm run build -- -c production` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the Trackly@5.2.5 build:prod script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\ankus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-04T07_50_40_145Z-debug.log npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Trackly@5.2.5 electron:windows: `npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build
--windows` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the Trackly@5.2.5 electron:windows script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\ankus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-04T07_50_40_174Z-debug.log
```

This is my app.module.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-mix';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import '../polyfills';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, forwardRef } from '@angular/core'; import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

// NG Translate import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core'; import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { ElectronService } from './providers/electron.service';

import { WebviewDirective } from './directives/webview.directive';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './components/task/task.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
import { AlertComponent } from './components/_directives/alert/alert.component'; import { AlertService } from './components/_services/alert.service';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { AuthGuard } from './components/_guards/auth.guard';
import { TimeConvertPipe } from './components/_pipes/time-convert.pipe';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component'; import { HttpService } from './components/_services/http.service';
import { DataService } from './components/_services/data.service';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { NgxMaterialTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
import { ObjectKeyPipe } from './components/_pipes/object-key.pipe';
import { HelpComponent } from './components/help/help.component';
import { CheckComponent } from './components/check/check.component';
import { NoteComponent } from './components/modals/note/note.component';
import { SettingModalComponent } from './components/modals/setting-modal/setting-modal.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';


// AoT requires an exported function for factories export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json'); }

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TaskComponent,
    WebviewDirective,
    LoginComponent,
    AlertComponent,
    TimeConvertPipe,
    DashboardComponent,
    ObjectKeyPipe,
    HelpComponent,
    CheckComponent,
    NoteComponent,
    SettingModalComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    forwardRef(() => ElectronService),
    forwardRef(() => AlertService),
    forwardRef(() => AuthGuard),
    forwardRef(() => HttpService),
    forwardRef(() => DataService),
    // ElectronService,
    // AlertService,
    // AuthGuard,
    // HttpService,
    // DataService   ],   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    routing,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    forwardRef(() => NgxMaterialTimepickerModule.forRoot())
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    NoteComponent,
    SettingModalComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tried using forward ref in for services but i'm still getting the same error.

This is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "Trackly",
  "version": "5.2.5",
  "description": "Time tracking electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run postinstall:electron && npx electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postinstall:web": "node postinstall-web",
    "postinstall:electron": "node postinstall",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run postinstall:electron && npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve",
    "build": "npm run postinstall:electron && npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve",
    "ng:serve:web": "npm run postinstall:web && ng serve -o",
    "electron:serve-tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig-serve.json",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on http-get://localhost:4200/ && npm run electron:serve-tsc && electron . --serve",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && electron .",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --linux",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --windows",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --mac",
    "test": "npm run postinstall:web && ng test",
    "e2e": "npm run postinstall:web && ng e2e",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/cron": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/node-notifier": "0.0.28",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "cron": "^1.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "iohook": "^0.2.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^2.11.1",
    "node-gyp": "^3.8.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "7.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "7.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "3.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "^2.0.11",
    "core-js": "2.5.6",
    "electron": "^3.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "20.28.1",
    "electron-reload": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.3",
    "npx": "10.2.0",
    "protractor": "5.3.2",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "ts-node": "6.0.3",
    "tslint": "5.10.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6",
    "wait-on": "2.1.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.0.6",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  }
}
```